# Using jQuery .append to build table yielding incorrect html

Tags: jquery

I wrote the following javascript to dynamically build a calendar and append it to a designated div.  It works and the calendar looks fine in the browser.

```
$('#Calendar').append('<table><thead><th>Monday</th><th>Tuesday</th><th>Wednesday</th><th>Thursday</th><th>Friday</th><th>Saturday</th><th>Sunday</th></thead><tr>');

for (i = 0; i <= loop; i++) {
    if ((i == 7) || (i == 14) || (i == 21) || (i == 28) || (i == 35)) {
        $('#Calendar').append(loopDate.getDate() + "</tr><tr>");
        $('#Calendar').append('<td>' + loopDate.getDate() + '</td>');
        loopDate.addDays(1);
    } else {
        $('#Calendar').append('<td>' + loopDate.getDate() + '</td>');
        loopDate.addDays(1);
    }
}
$('#Calendar').append('</table>');

}
```

However, when I inspect the resulting HTML for the page I see that my `<tr></tr>` are not landing in the correct place.  There also appears to be an extraneous appended .  Can someone please explain to me why this is happening?

```
<div id="Calendar">
<div></div>
<table>
 <thead>
  <tr>
  <th>Monday</th>
  <th>Tuesday</th>
  <th>Wednesday</th>
  <th>Thursday</th>
  <th>Friday</th>
  <th>Saturday</th>
  <th>Sunday</th>
  </tr></thead>
  <tbody>
  <tr></tr>
  </tbody>
  </table>
  <td>26</td>
  <td>27</td>
  <td>28</td>
  <td>29</td>
  <td>30</td>
  <td>31</td>
  <td>1</td>
  <tr></tr>
  <td>2</td>
  <td>3</td>
  <td>4</td>
  <td>5</td>
  <td>6</td>
  <td>7</td>
  <td>8</td>
  <tr></tr>
  <td>9</td>
  <td>10</td>
  <td>11</td>
  <td>12</td>
  <td>13</td>
  <td>14</td>
  <td>15</td>
  <tr></tr>
  <td>16</td>
  <td>17</td>
  <td>18</td>
  <td>19</td>
  <td>20</td>
  <td>21</td>
  <td>22</td>
  <tr></tr>
  <td>23</td>
  <td>24</td>
  <td>25</td>
  <td>26</td>
  <td>27</td>
  <td>28</td>
  <td>29</td>
  </div>
```

Comment: For some reason, jQuery lets you *"append"* html, which makes it look like your code should work. You should be aware then when dealing with the real DOM API, the only thing you can *"append"* is DOM nodes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery methods such as `append()` manipulate the browser's DOM tree.
The DOM holds *complete* HTML elements.  You can't put in half of a tag.

Instead, you can concatenate HTML into a string (or, for better performance, an array), then put the complete HTML string into the DOM at once.